# Is it possible to have an element positioned outside of @page margins?

Tags: css

If I have a `@print` stylesheet set up with 60mm margins, is it possible to have a logo appear with `position: fixed;` at 20mm from the top of the page? Thus far it appears that everything outside of the `@page` margins gets cropped.

It’s difficult to actually *see* the issue in the code snippet below, but check it out here: https://jsbin.com/xaxanamihu/edit?html,css,output

And the pure output here: https://output.jsbin.com/xaxanamihu

View the print preview of that page. You’ll see the `.logo` div is cropped because its position is technically outside of the view area set by `@page` margins.

I basically need to mimic the concept of a header and footer in my print styles from, say, an Apple Pages or Word document. The same logo in the header and small text in the footer on every page, with the content area given plenty of margin for the header and footer.

```css
.logo {
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
}

@page {
 size: auto;
 margin: 60mm;
}

@media print {
  .logo {
    background: black;
    left: -50px;
    top: -50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">Logo.</div>
```

Comment: Can u share your code?

Comment: There ya go, Shashank!

Comment: @BrandonDurham Did you ever find a way to do this?